# How to import a certificate with private key on Certificate Management Tool

Tags: certificate, private-key, makecert

By now the only way i'm able to import a certificate on Certificate Management Tool is by having a .pfx file. I'm using Makecert.exe utility to generate certificates.

First Step - I generate a Certification Authority by using the following command:

```
makecert.exe -n "CN=TestCA" -r -sv TestCA.pvk TestCA.cer
```

Second Step - I generated the private key file and the certificate file

```
makecert.exe -n "CN=TestCert" -sv TestCert.pvk -iv TestCA.pvk -ic TestCA.cer TestCert.cer -sky signature -pe
```

Now I'm able to see that I generated 4 Files, TestCA.pvk, TestCA.cer, TestCert.pvk, TestCert.cer

When importing i'm not able to choose a pvk file from the Certificate Management Tool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After researching a little, I found a microsoft utility named Pvk2Pfx.exe to overcome this issue.

This utility takes two files and merges them into one .PFX File which is what Certification Management Tool uses to import Certificates with private keys.

Here is the documentation to use it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550672(v=vs.85).aspx

And I will add the full command used to generate de .pfx File

```
pvk2pfx -pvk TestCert.pvk -pi TestCertPassword -spc TestCert.cert -pfx TestCert.pfx -po TestCertPassword -f
```